# List of object, get property with separator

Tags: c#, list

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I have a list :

```
List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
```

I'd like get, the Id value of all entries of the list with comma separator, like this : *id1, id2, id3*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [string.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx) to join values and [Enumerable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) to selected desired values:

```
string allIds = string.Join(", ", list.Select(i => i.Id.ToString()));
```